# Model domain when a lot of objects have a validity (start-end) that define the relationship between objects

Tags: design-patterns, model

A lot of our objects have relations that are defined with a start - endDate.
This makes it hard to model our domain.
for example: a person belongs to a serie, and a serie belongs to an organisation, and an organisation belongs to a location, ...
All these relationships have a start and enddate.
How can we model this. Now, we keep lists that identify these relations in time, and we constantly need to loop this list to find a valid object on a certain date.

Answer (score 0):

One possible option would be to keep the entities as is, but remove the time aspect from the object and create a separate entity that couples these object together based on a time range property.

You then could use composition to associate the objects.

For example if your organization had a property that was this "time relationship" object it would know if it belonged to a location based on this property.

Hope this helps a little.